# WPF User Control as item template

Tags: wpf, button, datatemplate, wrappanel, gaps-in-visuals

Hi
I am trying to render buttons as the item template of a list, to be displayed  horizontally. The problem is that they don't 'butt up' to each other. They leave a small gap betwen each one. I have tried allsorts of things to cure it, but have'nt succeeded.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the WPF tool [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to work out where the margin is coming from, and then fix it.

(Negative margins = code smell, in general, IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative margin, setting cliptobounds to false, maybe that can help

Comment: I know it is a bad practice, but if you need something *quick* it could of work...

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely either a Border, Margin, or Padding on your item container (i.e. ListBoxItem if you're using ListBox) which can be corrected with the ItemContainerStyle or your Button's Border is using BorderThickness=1, BorderBrush=Transparent or null.

Use Snoop as Dan suggested to find out.